# Chat server/client using ASIO, unable to find the client example code

Tags: c++, tcp, asio, coroutinescope

I'm about to use [ASIO](https://think-async.com/Asio/) for a chat server/client. When I downloaded ASIO, it had built-in examples for the different C++ versions. Since I will be using C++ 17/20, I decided to take that particular example.

The problem is that it is missing the client example. Can I find their client example code somewhere for C++ 17/20? By C++ 17/20 I mean the client should use *coroutines*.

[image]

#### chat_server.cpp

```cpp
//
// chat_server.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2020 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/detached.hpp>
#include <asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <asio/read_until.hpp>
#include <asio/redirect_error.hpp>
#include <asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/write.hpp>

using asio::ip::tcp;
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::co_spawn;
using asio::detached;
using asio::redirect_error;
using asio::use_awaitable;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_participant
{
public:
  virtual ~chat_participant() {}
  virtual void deliver(const std::string& msg) = 0;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<chat_participant> chat_participant_ptr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_room
{
public:
  void join(chat_participant_ptr participant)
  {
    participants_.insert(participant);
    for (auto msg: recent_msgs_)
      participant->deliver(msg);
  }

  void leave(chat_participant_ptr participant)
  {
    participants_.erase(participant);
  }

  void deliver(const std::string& msg)
  {
    recent_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    while (recent_msgs_.size() > max_recent_msgs)
      recent_msgs_.pop_front();

    for (auto participant: participants_)
      participant->deliver(msg);
  }

private:
  std::set<chat_participant_ptr> participants_;
  enum { max_recent_msgs = 100 };
  std::deque<std::string> recent_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_session
  : public chat_participant,
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<chat_session>
{
public:
  chat_session(tcp::socket socket, chat_room& room)
    : socket_(std::move(socket)),
      timer_(socket_.get_executor()),
      room_(room)
  {
    timer_.expires_at(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max());
  }

  void start()
  {
    room_.join(shared_from_this());

    co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
        [self = shared_from_this()]{ return self->reader(); },
        detached);

    co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
        [self = shared_from_this()]{ return self->writer(); },
        detached);
  }

  void deliver(const std::string& msg)
  {
    write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    timer_.cancel_one();
  }

private:
  awaitable<void> reader()
  {
    try
    {
      for (std::string read_msg;;)
      {
        std::size_t n = co_await asio::async_read_until(socket_,
            asio::dynamic_buffer(read_msg, 1024), "\n", use_awaitable);

        room_.deliver(read_msg.substr(0, n));
        read_msg.erase(0, n);
      }
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
      stop();
    }
  }

  awaitable<void> writer()
  {
    try
    {
      while (socket_.is_open())
      {
        if (write_msgs_.empty())
        {
          asio::error_code ec;
          co_await timer_.async_wait(redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));
        }
        else
        {
          co_await asio::async_write(socket_,
              asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front()), use_awaitable);
          write_msgs_.pop_front();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
      stop();
    }
  }

  void stop()
  {
    room_.leave(shared_from_this());
    socket_.close();
    timer_.cancel();
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  asio::steady_timer timer_;
  chat_room& room_;
  std::deque<std::string> write_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

awaitable<void> listener(tcp::acceptor acceptor)
{
  chat_room room;

  for (;;)
  {
    std::make_shared<chat_session>(
        co_await acceptor.async_accept(use_awaitable),
        room
      )->start();
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc < 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: chat_server <port> [<port> ...]\n";
      return 1;
    }

    asio::io_context io_context(1);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
      unsigned short port = std::atoi(argv[i]);
      co_spawn(io_context,
          listener(tcp::acceptor(io_context, {tcp::v4(), port})),
          detached);
    }

    asio::signal_set signals(io_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    signals.async_wait([&](auto, auto){ io_context.stop(); });

    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

I tried to create a client myself, but I'm not able to write messages and everyone to be able to read them yet, basically what the C++ 11 example chat client code does.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

#include <asio.hpp>

using asio::ip::tcp;
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::co_spawn;
using asio::detached;
using asio::redirect_error;
using asio::use_awaitable;

std::deque<std::string> write_msgs_;

void stop(tcp::socket& socket)
{
    socket.close();
}

awaitable<void> reader(tcp::socket& socket)
{
    try
    {
        for (std::string read_msg;;)
        {
            std::size_t n = co_await asio::async_read_until(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(read_msg, 1024), "\n", use_awaitable);

            //room_.deliver(read_msg.substr(0, n));
            read_msg.erase(0, n);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
        stop(socket);
    }
}

awaitable<void> writer(tcp::socket& socket)
{
    try
    {
        while (socket.is_open())
        {
            if (write_msgs_.empty())
            {
                asio::error_code ec;
                //co_await timer_.async_wait(redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));
            }
            else
            {
                co_await asio::async_write(socket, asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front()), use_awaitable);
                write_msgs_.pop_front();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
        stop(socket);
    }
}

awaitable<void> connect(tcp::socket socket, const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    std::error_code ec;

    co_await socket.async_connect(endpoint, redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));

    co_spawn(socket.get_executor(), [&] { return reader(socket); }, detached);
    co_spawn(socket.get_executor(), [&] { return writer(socket); }, detached);

    if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Connected to " << endpoint << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        asio::io_context io_context(1);
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1"), 666);
        tcp::socket socket(io_context);

        co_spawn(io_context, connect(std::move(socket), endpoint), detached);

        asio::signal_set signals(io_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
        signals.async_wait([&](auto, auto) { io_context.stop(); });
        
        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use client server from C++11 example ? As I understand it compiles and works for C++17.

Comment: @chandola, it's not so compatible. The server uses the coroutines from C++ 20 and the client from C++ 11 doesn't. The C++ 20 accepts a string, while C++ 11 is using a message class.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought you need an example for client and server. c++11 section have both client and server example but without co routines.

Comment: You mention "C++17" a number of times -- but if you're using coroutines, then that's only in C++20 and above (unless you're using a compiler-specific extension)

Comment: @Human-Compiler, the example is in folder cpp17 folder, even tho it is C++ 20. That's why.